# BAT FILE: Rename wav files in directory with the exception of a single file name?

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to write a bat file that does this:

1. Deletes two files: Temp.Wav Temp.lip
2. Renames any wav file in the directory to temp.wav

I'm stumped unfortunately, been at it for hours.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for %%F in (*.wav) do (
  set "name=%%F"
  ren "!name!" "!name:Temp.wav!"
)
```

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: @bentley5, if you have more than one `.wav` in the folder where the Batch file is working, how do you plan to rename them? You aim to use an increment number attached to the file name? Please, provide us more detailed information about you issue so we can be able to clearly answer to your question.

Comment: There will only be a single wav file after temp.lip and temp.wav are deleted, wouldn't - ren *.wav Temp.wav - work to rename any wav in the folder?

Answer (score 0):

This task is very easy to solve with a small batch file. The directory path on second line must be adapted.

```
@echo off
set "WorkingDirectory=C:\Temp\WavFiles"

if exist "%WorkingDirectory%\Temp.wav" del "%WorkingDirectory%\Temp.wav"
if exist "%WorkingDirectory%\Temp.lip" del "%WorkingDirectory%\Temp.lip"

rem The loop below renames just first found *.wav file in the directory.
for %%F in ("%WorkingDirectory%\*.wav") do (
   ren "%%F" Temp.wav
   goto :EndBatch
)
:EndBatch
set WorkingDirectory=
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a minimalist way of doing it - remove the `cd` command to make it operate in the current folder.

```
@echo off
cd /d "c:\folder"
del Temp.wav 2>nul
del Temp.lip 2>nul
ren *.wav Temp.wav 2>nul
```